# Insantiate list dynamic one line

Tags: apex, list, dynamic, schema, sobjecttype

So I am able to return the sobject of a list like so:

```
//sobjectlist = list of records passed into fuction.


Schema.SObjectType sotype = sobjectList.getsObjectType();
```

Now this gives me `sotype` with stores the actual type of sobject passed in.
I was trying to do the following:

```
List<sObject> output = (List<sObject>)soType.newInstance();
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Schema.SObjectType].newInstance()

If it's possible, my ultimate goal is to do something like this:

```
List<SObject> output = (List<SObject>)getSObjectType(sobjectList).newInstance();
```

But this tosses the following error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: getSObjectType(List)

Is there a way to dynamically detect the type of a list and then create a new instance of it in one line? I'm at a loss as to what I am getting wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `List<SObject>` and you want another `List` of the same type, use `clone`:

```
public List<SObject> getNewList(List<SObject> input)
{
    List<SObject> newList = input.clone();
    newList.clear();
    return newList;
}
```

If you want to instantiate a `List<SObject>` given an `SObjectType`, you will have to construct the `Type` yourself. The `Type` class does have an instance method named `newInstance`.

```
public List<SObject> getNewList(SObjectType listType)
{
    String typeName = 'List<' + listType + '>';
    return (List<SObject>)Type.forName(typeName).newInstance();
}
```

This latter does allow for a one-line approach if you desire (simply don't cache `typeName`). If you wanted to accept a `List<SObject>` parameter, you can still adopt this approach in one line:

```
public List<SObject> getNewList(List<SObject> input)
{
    return (List<SObject>)Type.forName('List<' + input.getSObjectType() + '>').newInstance();
}
```

---

From an `SObjectType`, you can instantiate a *single record* with the `newSObject` method:

```
public SObject getNewRecord(SObjectType sObjectType)
{
    return sObjectType.newSObject();
}
```

Or, if you really wanted to use `Type` and `newInstance`, you can get its `Type` using the static `Type.forName` method:

```
public SObject getNewRecord(SObjectType sObjectType)
{
    return (SObject)Type.forName(String.valueOf(sObjectType)).newInstance();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the multiple examples as well. I wasn't dead set on any one way of accomplishing the goal, so this is very helpful. Thanks Adrian!

Comment: Quick Note: When I try example 3 it's returning the following error: `Return value must be of type: List<SObject>' Edit: So is #2